# When not to use NotUsed in Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have seen a lot of Akka stream examples that use `NotUsed`, but I have not been able to find one where something other than `NotUsed` was used. I tried creating a source that does not have NotUsed, but it does not seem to be passed to the next flow. I would appreciate if someone can explain when and how we want to have something other than `NotUsed`.

Answer (score 2):

This part of Akka Streams documentation details the "materialized value" and how they compose (so that you can pass what you need to the next flow): https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-composition.html#materialized-values

Also other parts of the documentation also use not-NotUsed values.

Like in the first snippet [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#defining-and-running-streams)

```scala
val source = Source(1 to 10)
val sink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)

// connect the Source to the Sink, obtaining a RunnableGraph
val runnable: RunnableGraph[Future[Int]] = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right)

// materialize the flow and get the value of the sink
val sum: Future[Int] = runnable.run()
```